# Make readline tab cycle options within a C application

Tags: c, autocomplete, readline

When using bash, if you run `bind 'TAB:menu-complete'` readline will cycle through all the possible matches. However I can't find a way to do the same in a C program that uses `readline` for input.

The question is not about how to use `readline` autocompletion as I already have it working. I just want to tab cycle instead of dumping all possible completions on the screen.

Comment: I have this probably useful idea: coredump bash and see what is the content of readline global variables. Maybe I will get somewhere.